# How to combine two string in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, echo, smarty3

Why doesn't this work in Smarty?

```
{my_function($test.'a1')}
```

It's showing following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message
'Syntax Error in template "test.tpl" on line 1 "{my_function($test.'a1')}"
Unexpected "'a1'", expected one of: "{" , "$" , "identifier" , INTEGER' in...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have only used smarty a little but I think if you surround your concatenation with backticks then it will evaluate them properly. Example below:

```
{my_function(`$test.'a1'`)}
```

There is also the assign built in function which may also be useful: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign

Finally, if all else fails do the concat in php and assign it to a single variable and passing that to the template.

---

Edit, ignore the above suggestions, I think you should be using the following syntax:

```
{my_function var="`$test`a1"}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl

Comment: Pretty much the same for v3: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing it passing into a function you can do a capture or assign

```
{capture assign="parameter"}{$test}a1{/capture} {my_function($parameter)}

{assign var="parameter" value=$test|cat:"a1"} {my_function($parameter)}
```

I have not tried using a modifier on the parameter to a function. But you could try it out. Also since its a custom smarty function you could add a third optional parameter and concatenate the values in side the function.

```
<?php

function smarty_function_my_function($params, $smarty) {
   $input = join('', $params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Smarty *does not understand PHP syntax*. It uses it's own syntax as [described here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/) and quickly compared to [PHP syntax here](http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison). (I have included the latter link to reinforce the point -- Smarty syntax is Smarty syntax.)

See the section on [embedding vars in double quotes](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl) which should given an idea of how to accomplish the task. (Hint: for this case back-ticks must be used *inside* the quotes).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code and works fine for me

Location **smarty\plugins\function.concat.php**

```
<?php
function smarty_function_concat($params){
    return implode('', $params);
}
?>
```

On .tpl code:

> {concat 1="string1" 2="second" 3="an other string"}